# 2D-iPhone-Game with side-scrolling & platforms like Super Mario with Cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, 2d

I want to create a game where the player only can run and jump on platforms. I think Cocos2D would be great for that but i haven't found any tutorials for cocos2d and side-scrolling. Where I have to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by learning how to use Cocos2D, its basics, how it works,etc. Then you can use one of the 2 included physics systems: Chipmunk or Box2D (or roll out your own solution).
Setting a simple scene with Chipmunk should give you a good start. There will be some issues you will find like handling slopes, one-way platforms,etc. You can check the chipmunk forums, there are a couple of questions regarding that in there: http://www.slembcke.net/forums/

Also, consider buying this from the Cocos2d developer: http://www.sapusmedia.com/levelsvg/ it contains lots of solutions to problems you might find.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has already been answered, but here is something right up your alley:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15230/how-to-make-a-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15267/how-to-make-a-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-2

This is precisely what you're looking for.  Besides, Ray Wenderlich's site is a gold mine for awesome tutorials on video game tutorials using Cocos2D.

I hope this helps!